# IOS app with Age Rating 17+ not visible in United Arab Emirates

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Here is the link for my ios App
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id1479515044

This app is a Contest specifically made to the users in United Arab Emirates. We have not restricted it as of now to UAE and is visible all over for all countries. Now the problem is that the app in not visible in UAE because if has an **Age Rating of 17+** and falls under **Gambling and Contests**.

Earlier the app was rejected by Apple when I had sent for review with Age Rating 4+ and Apple asked me to put it under Gambling and Contests after which it was approved.

Now the dilemma is how can I make it visible in UAE. Any Specific Age Rating I should be using?

What are the next procedures?

**About the App.**
App allows users to upload a 1 minute video which is first review by the backend team and then made available to be viewed. The video with most likes had a chance to win the prize money and  top 3 has a chance to participate in a live show.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I pretty sure that you can't. Since Apple review team won't approve your app if it doesn't have the correct rating and UAE local laws prohibit Apple from listing apps with the age rating of 17+.

Comment: yes. I know that. But there would be other app with similar kind of content like my app which must be live. 
Also is there a provision to take approval from UAE officials to make the app live in that region.

Comment: No it's simply not possible. They will not make any exceptions. It would require them to go through a rigorous legal review/vetting process, which probably does economically not make sense for them.